# Formatting (string-) array as part of bean-validation message

Tags: java, bean-validation

I created my first custom validation annotation with validator class as inner class (which i find quite well-arranged).
It looks like this:

```
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {OneOfGroupNotNull.Validator.class})
@Documented
public @interface OneOfGroupNotNull {

    // custom annotation properties
    String[] fields();

    // required by JSR-303
    String message() default "One of group must be not null. {fields}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    public class Validator implements ConstraintValidator<OneOfGroupNotNull, Object> {

        private String[] fields;

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {

            int countNotNull = 0;

            for (String field : fields) {
                try {
                    String property = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, field);
                    if (property != null) {
                        countNotNull++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Validation for field " + field + " of type " + bean.getClass()+ " raised exception.", ex);
                }
            }

            return countNotNull == 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(OneOfGroupNotNull a) {
            fields = a.fields();
        }
    }
}
```

A bean class that is annotated with this validator may look like this:

```
@OneOfGroupNotNull(fields = {"a", "b", "c"})
public interface MyBean {
    String getA();
    Rarity getB();
    Boolean getC();
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to format the string array "fields". It just takes the to string method which results in something like:
One of group must be not null. [Ljava.lang.String;@157d954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed type of `fields` from `String[]` to `String` then message with field names will be shown correctly. To get field names in constraint just `split()` it by comma.

Another option is to generating custom message inside constraint, like this:

```
cvc.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
cvc.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("error message")
    .addNode("field name with error")
    .addConstraintViolation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation of Bean Validation are you using? If you are using Hibernate Validator 4.3 this should actually work. See also https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HV-506.

As a workaround, why not use a *List*? There the default *toString* is more sensible.

Comment: 1. I am using Hibernate and it doesn't work out of the box. 2. A List is not a valid attribute for annotations.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Validator are you using? We fixed this in 4.3, maybe you're using an onlder version? I just tried out your constraint and got the error message "One of group must be not null. [a, b, c]".